# Error when doing linear regression using zoo objects ... Error in `$<-.zoo`(`*tmp*`

Tags: r, date

I am new to R and slowly getting acquainted.  My question refers to the following piece of code.

I am creating a zoo object with the following headers and then filtering by date.  On the filtered dates I am subtracting two columns (Tom from Elena).  Everything works fine until here.

Code below:

> b <- read.zoo(b1, header = TRUE, index.column = 1, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
>
> startDate = "2013/11/02"
> endDate = "2013/12/20"
>
> dates <- seq(as.Date(startDate), as.Date(endDate), by=1)
>
> TE = b[dates]$Tom - b[dates]$Elena

However I am then regressing the results from my subtraction (see above TE) on Elena.  However i get an error message every time i try and to this regression

> TE$model <- lm(TE ~ b[dates]$Elena)

Error in `$<-.zoo`(`*tmp*`, "model", value = list(coefficients = c(-0.0597128230859905,  :
not possible for univariate zoo series

I have tried creating a data frame and then doing the regression but with no avail.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add the outcome of a regression (a list of class `lm`) to a time series of class `zoo`.

I recommend saving the model in a separate object, e.g.,

```
fit <- lm(TE ~ b[dates]$Elena)
```

Comment: I am using the lmfit function and i can now do the regression.